# Why is MA not provable from ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, axioms, forcing, infinitary-combinatorics

All texts I have seen about Martin's Axiom briefly mention that it is independent of ZFC, that it is implied by CH and that it is relatively consistent with ZFC+(not CH). I have seen proofs of the latter two statements, but I cannot find any proof for the first one.

Specifically, what is missing is a proof that ZFC does not imply Martin's Axiom. Is this somehow obvious? Since CH implies MA, any model of ZFC which does not satisfy MA also cannot satisfy CH, so we do need Forcing for this proof, right?

Comment: For those who are not familiar with "Martin's Axiom":https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_axiom

Comment: Since MA implies that $2^\kappa\le2^{\aleph_0}$ whenever $\kappa\lt2^{\aleph_o}$, all you need to falsify MA is a model where $\aleph_1\lt2^{\aleph_0}\lt2^{\aleph_1}$.

Comment: Making bof's comment a bit more explicit: do you know how to get a model where $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ and $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_3$? If so, that's a model in which $\mathsf{MA}$ fails - and if not, that's a good exercise.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @NoahSchweber's suggestion sounds promising. I know how to get a model where $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$, but I am not sure how to make one where $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_3$.

If I start with a ctm $M$ of ZFC and let $P:=\mathrm{Fn}(\omega_2\times\omega,2)\times\mathrm{Fn}(\omega_3\times\omega_1,2)$, and let $G$ be a $P$-generic filter over $M$, will $M[G]$ do?

Sorry for the dumb questions, I am trying to learn Forcing just from Kunen's "Set theory" and my understanding is quite limited.

Answer (score 5):

There are **so many** reasons, and which one you want to use depends a lot on what you may consider as simpler and which consequences of Martin's Axiom you may be familiar with.

1. Adding a single Cohen real will add a Suslin tree. Add a Cohen real to any model of $\sf ZFC+\lnot CH$, and you will have a model in which there is a Suslin tree, and therefore Martin's Axiom fail.
2. Adding $\aleph_3$ Cohen reals to a model of $\sf ZFC+GCH$ will satisfy that $\sf CH$ fails, but at the same time, every real is either in the ground model, or Cohen generic over the ground model (i.e. generic for a countable forcing). Taking Random, Hechler, or many other type of c.c.c. reals which are not added by Cohen forcing, we have that these forcings have $\aleph_2$ dense sets in the ground model, but since $\aleph_2<2^{\aleph_0}$ in the generic extension, we should be able to find these type of reals.

   This can be done with Random reals, or other type of reals where we know of easy "c.c.c. reals which are not added".
3. As bof suggests, since Martin's Axiom imply that ${\sf\lnot CH}\to 2^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_0}$, all we need is to negate that. Easton's theorem tells us that this is quite easy to do.
4. Cichon's diagram of cardinal characteristics becomes somewhat trivial under Martin's Axiom, all but $\aleph_1$ will be equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$. So any result separating the characteristics (e.g. small non-meager sets, or small non-measurable sets, or small unbounded families, or small dominating families, to name a few) will imply that Martin's Axiom fail. This area is studied extensively, and in fact many of the basic results have simple constructions: adding $\aleph_1$ Cohen reals will add an unbounded family of size $\aleph_1$ to any model of $\sf ZFC$, in particular one where $\sf CH$ was already failing.

And there are probably other approaches one can take. This is by no means an exhaustive list.

Comment: "every real is either in the ground model, or Cohen generic over the ground model" No ?!? You add new reals to every perfect set, in particular nowhere dense ones. I guess you mean, generic for some countable forcing, so "basically" Cohen forcing.

Comment: @Jonathan: Correct me if I'm wrong here: $\operatorname{Add}(\omega,\kappa)$ is a ccc forcing, therefore every real is added by a countable subforcing, so every real not in the ground model is added by a Cohen forcing, and is therefore Cohen over the ground model.

Comment: Okay, I think we agree and just disagree on the meaning of "Cohen generic".

Comment: I know that you know, but just in case for the asker the reason MA is incompatible with a Suslin tree is that MA implies that the product of ccc posets is ccc, while if $T$ is a normal Suslin tree, then $T$ is ccc but $T\times T$ is not

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: And because if $T$ is a Suslin tree, let $D_\alpha$ be the tree above the $\alpha$th level, if CH fails, then there is a generic for $\{D_\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\}$, which has to be a cofinal branch. But if $T$ is Suslin, then there are none. This doesn't work with Aronszajn trees since they are not necessarily ccc, of course.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: And because $\sf{MA}(\aleph_1)$ implies that every tree of height and size $\omega_1$ without $\omega_1$-branches is special (can be written as a countable union of antichains), while a Suslin tree clearly isn't because it has small antichains. I guess we can come up with a few dozens more reasons if we try hard enough :P

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: Yes, we probably can. My point is that using productivity of ccc is quite the heavy gun (even heavier than "every A-tree is special"), and instead a direct argument can be made.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Off-topic-ish question: does every model of $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$ contain a (definable-with-parameters) inner model of $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg MA}$?

Comment: @Noah: That's a nice question. I suspect that yes, because you have $2^{\aleph_0}$ reals which are Cohen generic over $L$. So I think you can find $\aleph_2^L$ of them which work together as a witness. (We really only need to check this if $\aleph_2^L$ is uncountable in $V$.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, why do you have continuum-many Cohen-over-$L$s? Is it obvious that you can force $\neg\mathsf{CH}$ without adding a Cohen real?

Comment: @Noah: Because there are only $\aleph_1$ dense open subsets in $L$, so they admit a generic. And by recursion we can iterate this upwards all the way below the real continuum. So at least if $\aleph_2^L<2^{\aleph_0}$, we are done.

Comment: @Noah: I'm not even sure if we need that $\aleph_2^L<2^{\aleph_0}$. I think that the recursion just works all the way to the continuum. But I'm not 100% focused right now, and I may have made a mistake.

Comment: Why does adding $\aleph_1$ Cohen reals also add an unbounded family of size $\aleph_1$?

Comment: @Grinsekotze: No Cohen real is bounded by ground model reals; if you add $\aleph_1$ Cohen reals, then any real is either in the ground model, or is added by a countable part (which is isomorphic to one Cohen real), and so there is a lot of new reals not bounded by it. So the family of generic reals is unbounded.